# How can I install the Python 2 PDFWriter module in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I typed

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install PDFWriter
```

but I get the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package PDFWriter
```

Comment: What's PDFWriter? Are you sure there's an Ubuntu version of that application?

Comment: No I am not sure, just tell me i can do it or not?

Comment: You can search packages by typing `apt-cache search package`. Also, package names are usually (always?) full lowercase.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine, its give the following o/p:pslib1 - library to create PostScript files
pslib1-dbg - library to create PostScript files

Comment: apt is telling you the truth: There is no such application as "PDFWriter" in the Ubuntu repositories. Are you picking names at random? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: -1 then, "*this question doesn't show any research effort*".

Comment: Actually I want to convert my html code to pdf file in python, So i want to install it

Comment: Then I believe it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ah, you seem to be trying to install the *python2 PDFWriter module*. Correct?

Comment: Yes @user535733

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be looking for `pdfrw`, a “PDF file manipulation library,” which [contains a class named `PdfWriter`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfrw/0.2#writing-pdfs). The respective Python package names are `python-pdfrw` (Python 2.7) and `python3-pdfrw` (Python 3.x).

As always, install them with your favourite package manager or via Apt (`sudo apt install PACKAGE-NAME...`).

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!